# Enable logging in Calendar.app for OS X 10.8

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, calendar.app, console.app

You used to be able to access a secret debug menu in iCal but this seems to have been removed in 10.8. Annoyingly the command used to enable logging seems not to work any more either.

Can anyone tell me how to enable logging in 10.8?

Answer (score 6):

The debug menu is still there.

To enable the debug menu within ical, run the following on the command line:

> defaults write com.apple.iCal IncludeDebugMenu 1

Since OS X 10.9 (mavericks), this has changed to

> defaults write com.apple.iCal CDB 1

Comment: Still works on Catalina.

Comment: Still works on Big Sur.

Answer (score 1):

This option has been removed and possibly won't come back.

You seem to be able to change the default days in week view – for example to 14 – with:

```
defaults write com.apple.iCal "n days of week" 14
```

Enter `defaults read com.apple.iCal` to check other possible options you can modify. The logging behavior can not be changed.

Read more on this Ask Different question: [How do I enable the Debug menu in Calendar?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58889/how-do-i-enable-the-debug-menu-in-calendar)